g_csrf_token not being passed in Safari v18
This doesn't seem to happen on Chrome, Firefox, or previous versions of Safari.
I have a sign in with Google button using the Javascript API with ux_mode: 'redirect', and do not have one tap enabled.
Upon redirecting back to my site, I verify g_csrf_token as described in Google's docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token
The problem is specific to Safari v18 shipped with Sequoia, which as far as I can tell is not sending g_csrf_token with the request.
Notably, when checking the "Storage" tab of the browser, the g_csrf_token can still be found,
Is there some kind of behavioral change with the new Safari I'm not aware of? My setup is pretty basic, but on the other hand I would've expected widespread issues if such a basic behavior was changed, so I'm a bit stumped on what's going on.
Extracted code below:
<div
  id="google-button"
  data-button-text="<%= button_text %>"
  data-client-id="<%= google_oauth_client_id %>"
  data-request-url="<%= request_url %>"
>
</div>

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: $('#google-button').data('client-id'),
    login_uri: $('#google-button').data('request-url'),
    ux_mode: 'redirect'
  });

  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById('google-button'),
    { ... }
  );
});

if params[:g_csrf_token].blank? || cookies[:g_csrf_token].blank? || params[:g_csrf_token] != cookies[:g_csrf_token]
  head :bad_request
end

